# How do I change the coding font in Matlab?

Tags: fonts, matlab

How do I change the coding font in Matlab?

I don't want to change the font permanently - it won't be Matlab anymore! But I still want to find out how to do it and play with it a bit.

(This whole idea started when I spent too much time looking for a bug, which turned out to be a typo. Small L looks the same as the number one. Aaargh.)

Comment: I now see that there are preference settings under File.

Comment: By all means change the font permanently! There's really no point in not being able to read your code easily. It'll feel like Matlab again very soon. FWIW, I use Bitstream Vera.

Comment: You're right. I've changed it permanently now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2008/09/01/choose-a-good-font-your-eyes-will-thank-you/) post by Mike from the MATLAB desktop team.

Comment: Thanks! I missed the preference settings under the File-tab. Great quick response. My eyes will be happy.